# AngularJS not loading "detail view" data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor

I have a list of items, which I want to be able to click on to load the detail view: `foo/123`. My `$stateProvider` variable defines 

    `...
    })
    .state('foo', {
      url: '/foo/:fooId',
      templateUrl: 'client/templates/foo.html',
      controller: 'FooViewCtrl as foo',
    });`

fooview.controller.js:

```
angular
  .module('AppName')
  .controller('FooViewCtrl', FooViewCtrl);

function FooViewCtrl ($scope, $reactive, $stateParams) {
  $reactive(this).attach($scope);

  let fooId = $stateParams.fooId;

  this.helpers({
    data() {
      var a = Data.findOne(fooId); //Meteor func
      console.log(a); //this runs and correctly outputs the object
      return a;
    }
  });
}
```

foo.html:

```
<ion-view title="{{foo.name}}">
  <ion-content>
    <p>{{foo.name}}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

What am I missing here? Am I correct in thinking that the data function returns something "as foo" which is then referenced as `foo` in foo.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used controllerAs think it might look like

```
<ion-view title="{{foo.data.name}}">
  <ion-content>
    <p>{{foo.data.name}}</p>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you!